# Problem: adding a shared condition to each of 4 PartialViews with different models on a single AspNetCore MVC view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Just FYI, I've looked at numerous related sites and, in fact, I was able to choose a method to display multiple Partial Views with different models on a single view page from that research, but this is as far as I got before the press of other business took me away.

I need to add a condition such as a where clause (e.g. `return View(_context.Alert.Where(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex));` to the following PartialViews in my Assemble.cshtml page:

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.EdxlCapMessageViewModel

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Assembled EDXL-CAP Message</title>
</head>

<!-- DetailsAlert -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsAlert", Model.Alert)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsAlert -->

<!-- DetailsInfo -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsInfo", Model.Info)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsInfo -->

<!-- DetailsArea -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsArea", Model.Area)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsArea -->

<!-- DetailsResource -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsResource", Model.Resource)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsResource -->
```

Currently this page displays the `DetailsXXXX` PartialViews with no values for the model items. The user gets to this page by selecting an Alert_Identifier common to all four views on the `AlertPick.cshtml` page:

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.EdxlCapMessageViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AlertPick";
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

@{
    <h4>@Model.Alerts.Count Alerts</h4>

    <form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="PickAlert" method="post">
        <select class="cap_select" id="cap_select" style="width:100%;max-width:95%;"
            asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="Model.Alert_Identifiers">
        <option>Select one</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="PickAlert" value="Pick Alert to Assemble EDXL-Cap Message" />
</form>
}
```

The user’s selection and submit brings up the `PickAlert.cshtml` page that shows the `Alert_Identifier` for each of the 4 `DetailsXXXX` pages in rows of a table with a submit button of value `Check XXXX` and a last, fifth row with the `Alert_Identifier` and submit button of value `Add All`.

```
@model IEnumerable<edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.Alert>
@using edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PickAlert";

}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

    <h4>Alert</h4>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.Message
</div>

<style>
    tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: lightBlue; }

    tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: white; }
</style>

<table class="smallText">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="alerts" asp-action="_DetailsAlert" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Check Alert">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="infos" asp-action="_DetailsInfo" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Check Info">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="areas" asp-action="_DetailsArea" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Check Area">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="resources" asp-action="_DetailsResource" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Check Resource">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="elementInput">

                    <span class="smallText">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Alert_Identifier) value
                        <input type="text" name="elementValue" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)" size="60" />
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form asp-area="" asp-controller="EdxlCapMessageViewModels" asp-action="Assemble" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.AlertIndex">
                    <input type="hidden"
                           name="Identifier"
                           value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Alert_Identifier)">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="Add All">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Each of the four individual data category pages display correctly, but the page displayed by the fifth row only displays the data category model items without the values for selected composite message (using the `Alert_Identifier`). This page represents the candidate finished product of the application – this is the `Assemble.cshtml` page, and will be very similar to the `Review.cshtml` and `Approve.cshtml` pages which will finish the application.

I'm getting down to the end of this project and any help here would be enormously appreciated. Once done and vetted it will go open source, hoping to attract more developers to implement the set of OASIS Emergency Management IT standards and specifications. It makes sense to help first responders and emergency managers do their work more effectively by sharing information (exchanging data) interoperably, hence the Emergency Data Exchange Language (EDXL) suite of specifications and standards.`</elevator pitch>`

Comment: This question has been up for a couple of days with no comments or answers. I'm wondering how I can improve the question to get a better response. On the last code block the first four rows display the single data category page with the correct values when that row's Check button is clicked, and the fifth row returns all four data categories, as it is intended but with no values, yet they both have nearly identical code. It seems like an interesting problem to me, but then, I'm stuck with it.

Comment: I tried to improve the question and add a screenshot, but I lack the reputation for that. Apparently I'll have to try to  produce a better question.